# Can't backup the mysql table with mysqldump. SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied for 'cond_instances'

Tags: mysql, database-backup

I am having trouble running `mysqldump` as the mysql root user. When I try to backup the `mysql` table I get this error:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied to user
'root'@'localhost' for table 'cond_instances' when using LOCK TABLES
```

Anyone seen that before? I've seen some references to my mysql and my mysqldump being different versions but when I run which they are in the same directory.

I am running MySQL 5.5.8.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you run `mysqldump` with `--skip-add-locks` ?

Comment: Aha, that fixed it. I realized just now that it wasn't the mysql table, it was the performance_schema table, which I see in some docs requires the --skip-add-locks.

Comment: I had the same problem... I'm using [automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/) I just added the parameter `--single-transaction` and everythings work correctly.

Comment: Maybe the problem could be a typo? "LOCK TABL" could be "LOCK TABLE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add --skip-add-locks to your mysqldump command

Answer (score 20):

--skip-add-locks doesn't work :

```
# mysqldump -u root -p`cat mysqlRoot.txt` --databases performance_schema --routines --quote-names --skip-add-locks > mysql_performance_schema

mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT,LOCK TABL command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'cond_instances' when using LOCK TABLES
```

you want --skip-lock-tables instead

Comment: This fixed it for me. I edited the automysqlbackup executable (on my install, in /usr/local/bin) to modify the declaration of opt and opt_fullschema to add in the --skip-lock-tables. The new config was     opt=( '--quote-names' '--opt' '--skip-lock-tables' ) and     opt_fullschema=( '--all-databases' '--routines' '--no-data' '--skip-lock-tables' )

Answer (score 12):

(I realize this comes 8 months late)

This is not a problem of locks, and the offered solutions merely bypass the real problem:

A **5.5** *mysqldump* application should not export the `performance_schema` database in the first place.

Based on my previous experience, I suggest that the `mysqldump` program you have used is a **5.1** version. How to tell? Issue:

```
mysqldump --version
```

A **5.1** client is unaware of the "futuristic" existence of `performance_schema` and therefore attempts to dump it. It is unaware that it should not.

Try and find the **5.5** version, and use it for dumping, without adding the suggested locks, and this should work well.

Comment: Using 5.5 version and problem persists

Comment: mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) has the same issue...

Comment: if you're using automysqlbackup like some of the users above, you need to add 'performance_schema' to CONFIG_db_exclude parameter in your  automysqlbackup.conf

Comment: I agree with Shlomi above that skipping the locks only bypasses the real problem.

This helped me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/134670/how-do-i-stop-automysqlbackup-throwing-lock-tables-error

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Shlomi Noach, performance_schema is not supposed to be backed up.

The easy way to fix this is to set the following in your config file:

```
CONFIG_db_exclude=( 'performance_schema' 'information_schema' )
```