# Couldn't execute 'show events' on mysqldump

Tags: mysql

While trying to backup all MySQL databases with mysqldump I get the following error:

`Couldn't execute 'show events': Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' to database 'performance_schema'`

Comment: related: http://serverfault.com/questions/268566/cant-backup-the-mysql-table-with-mysqldump-select-lock-tabl-command-denied-for

Comment: @rubo77, Not really, [this error is due to a bug](http://serverfault.com/a/664829/87017), that is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a virtual database so you will need to add the option [`--skip-events`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_events) to make it work.

Comment: The flag ```--skip-events``` is not mentioned in the docs and it doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: This flag is included in the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#option_mysqlpump_events.

Comment: You linked ```mysqlpump``` and ```--exclude-events```

Comment: No! I actually linked `--events`. Read at the end of that paragraph (or better, entirely).

Comment: Alright but still, the question is about mysqldump not mysqlpump

Comment: It works for mysqldump too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-stored-programs.html. Both are used for backup.

Answer (score 3):

The other two answers will *work*, but their rationale and explanation are wrong.

The error you're getting is **not due to** the database being virtual, but due to a bug with the query `show events`: [image]

> `SHOW EVENTS` in the performance_schema database returned an
>   access-denied error, rather than an empty result

The bug has been fixed in MySQL server 5.7.6. Simply update your server and you won't be seeing this error anymore.

In the meantime, if you are stuck with older versions of MySQL server, avoid calling `show events` by using the solutions provided in the other two answers.

Comment: This information is nowhere else to be found; at least not where I looked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you encountered this error with an ordinary database, you need to grant your user the [EVENT permission](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_event).

Answer (score 2):

'performance_schema' is a virtual database so you don't have to backup it
(see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html )

to skip it in your backup script use it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
BAK=/var/backups/mysql/
DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
MYSQLPATH=/var/lib/mysql/
for i in /var/lib/mysql/*/; do
    if [ $i != "$MYSQLPATH"'performance_schema/' ] ; then 
        dbname=`basename "$i"` 
        mysqldump -u root "$dbname" | gzip > $BAK/"$dbname"-$DATE.sql.gz
    fi
done

# optionally delete old backups of databases that don't exist anymore
# find $BACKUP_DIR -atime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: +1 I was actually using this in a similar script, but I haven't specify in my question. Anyway, good sharing.

Answer (score 2):

```
GRANT EVENT ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```